# Suddenly, ubuntu goes really, really slowly

Tags: 16.04, grub2, nvidia, xorg, lightdm

I have a laptop with a core i7, 16GB RAM, an SSD with GBs of free space on every partition,... and I've been working with Ubuntu for months without too many problem,... but today, something's wrong. The desktop? is really slow. 
I press print screen and it takes...23 SECONDS to show the dialog with the screenshot for me to save it...until today, this usually took 0.1 seconds

Other apps work normally, but something's wrong: on the previous sesion it took more than 10 seconds to open nautilus,... now it takes just 0.0 secs.
You press ctrl+alt+t and it takes about 20 seconds to open the terminal...
I have Ubuntu 16.04 with 4.8.8-040808-generic (I installed that kernel months ago)

Few days ago I had a problem installing an upgrade of the nvidia drivers, and I had to recreate the xorg.conf, grub.conf,... but I think all that's ok...
Most of the apps need 0.1 secs to be opened, but several other things go really slow

I don't know if it's related, but

1. In the last few days, when I restart the session back from suspend, sometimes it suspends itself as soon as I enter the credentials
2. Chromium forgot my credentials a few minutes ago,...
   ... and now, I've been a few minutes outside and nautilus requires 20 seconds again to start...

I use to update the software (apt dist-upgrade) almost everyday...
Is it a recent update? does anyone else have the same problem?
Thank you very much in advance
Kind regards

Here's my information about graphic card

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller    
    Kernel driver in use: i915  
    Kernel modules: i915

01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK208M [GeForce GT 740M] (rev a1)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company GK208M [GeForce GT 740M]
    Kernel driver in use: nvidia
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_375_drm, nvidia_375
```

Comment: Check your RAM usage when it is slow (`free -h` command) and your used graphics card and driver (`lspci -k | grep -iEA3 '3D|VGA'` command). You can [edit] your question to paste the output of these commands.

Comment: If you start a `terminal` and type `top`, which process pops up at the top of the list? At what CPU %? Have you rebooted your machine to see if that solves the problem?

Comment: It's not about resources: 10% CPU and 50% of memory in use. It doesn't look about graphics: to open a terminal requires 20 seconds but I can see a video, work with GIMP,... without any problem...

Comment: Hi @heynnema. Here it's my tops:   
(I know, too many browsers... but anyway, the CPU indicator says CPU it's at12% in use...)
PID USUARIO   PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     HORA+ ORDEN                                                                                           
25299 alucasr   20   0 2024900 384716  98712 S  56,1  2,4  11:07.18 chromium-browse                                                                                 
 8366 alucasr   20   0 1712468 530172 170328 S   9,3  3,2  13:58.42 chromium-browse

Comment: This is weird, probably significative...    
Ctrl+Alt+T requires about 20 seconds to open the terminal...   
... but if I press right click on a folder in nautilus and I select to open it in terminal, it takes 0.0 seconds to open it... 
Where is the difference? Could it be related with my home?

Comment: I'm doing some test, because guest acount works ok. Everything takes 0.0 secs to open...  
I'm reviewing my home, the SSD,...

Comment: You didn't say if you rebooted the machine yet. If guest account works fine, then there's potentially something in your home directory causing the problem. Have you edited any of `.profile` or `.bash*`?

Comment: It isn't on my profile. The guest works ok, but I have another user with same problems... and it's a new one, without content.    
I recently added another HD where I created ...about 20 partitions? I have two distributions already installed and space for another two (4 partition each: boot, root, home, swap). Guest do not see partitions (he doesn't have permissions, but the other user has...).   
The problem needs to be something like this... guest user doesn't have permissions but our users have...

Comment: Check the manufacturer's web site for a firmware update for the SSD.  Edit your question with the output of `sudo fdisk -l`, `sudo blkid`, and `cat /etc/fstab`. Open the `Disks` app, go to the "hamburger" icon, select `SMART Data & Tests`. Review the data, run the tests, report back. Start comments directed to me with `@heynnema` or I may miss them.

Comment: @heynnema Hi, I think the SSD works Ok. I made a SMART test that day and everything was ok.  
Here it's the information you requested:  
(too long to paste here)  
https://expirebox.com/download/37b9cdd07639e212d99a78341f079b09.html
  
Kind regards

Comment: You need to check that you've got the latest firmware in your SSD. You forgot the `cat /etc/fstab`, and why don't you also let me see `free -h` and `swapon`. If you have a UEFI machine, why isn't sda in GPT/GUID format? Why the 22G swap on sda? That's too big. For your other OS's... first question would be **why**? Second question would be why not in Virtualbox? Lastly, if you disconnect sdb, and reboot with just sda, does it all work faster then?

Comment: I'd still like to see fstab, and free -h, and swapon. You also didn't say why so many partitions/distributions vs Virtualbox VM's.

Comment: @heynnema Hi, I could run a lot of things, but a lot those test are really improbable. The system was working ok for months and, as I told before, there's plenty of space and RAM, so that's not the problem. The system starts with just 1GB of memory in use and 15GB free... but even without knowing that, I can start heavy tasks, with heavy graphical, CPU or memory requirements with no problem... but it takes more than 20 seconds to start a terminal, so the problem it's not graphical nor memory related...  It could be the second HD and all that partitions, it shouldn't be, but it could... (1/2)

Comment: The easy way to tell would be to temporarily disconnect the second drive, and then see if Ubuntu runs normally from the first drive.

Comment: @heynnema Hi. The second HD, the one with all those partitions, it has only one of them mounted, so, I think that should not affect the system.  
I have a big swap partition because I use it: 16GB for hibernation and a few more available for swapping.  
I have another partition with the previous Windows I had. I have only used it once in a year, but I want it there because I can need it. I don't want to use VirtualBox because it doesn't have any sense for me in the way I use it my OSs. I run Ubuntu normally and if I really, really, really need it, I start my windows with all my stuff there.

Comment: Yea, I think so...  
I really don't like it, but I think I will have to do that...  
I've opened the laptop several times in few days and it's easy to broke those little plastic flaps/tabs, so I would prefer not to do that, but I think I will have to in case I don't find any other test to do...  
I'm sending the information you requested...

Comment: In the second HD, I have a ParrotOS, a Kali and free space for another two distribution, just in case I need to test anything in the same conditions of the OS I already run...  
Here are the files...
https://expirebox.com/download/29db7ed7e429a509a3c743613234561a.html

Comment: The latest file looks normal to me.

Comment: @heynnema. I've disconnected the second HD, but it doesn't change anything.   
I've realised everything works ok when I don't use the shortcuts: if I open the terminal or nautilus from any other site or way, it's inmediate, but when I use the shortcuts, it takes more than 20 seconds. Other shortcuts worked ok...  until now: I've several work spaces ... until now.  Unity tweak tool shows I should have several work spaces, but they're not working, I've just one.
Maybe I should reinstall everything related to Unity tweak...

Comment: Yes, I think you've identified enough problems to warrant a reinstall.

Comment: Solved. Incredible. I've made a backup (clonezilla), I 've reinstalled and installed all the packages I had by lots and I've finally came out with the problem:   
apt remove dbus-user-session  
That solved all (I've recovered my previous installation and removed that package)
That package delays between 20 and 25 seconds to open a terminal with ctrl+T, to open nautilus (super+e), to get an screenshot (shift+print screen).  
It took time, but I hope it will help someone else...

Comment: If you have solved your problem, please post an answer instead of editing the question.

Answer (score 3):

**Problem**: several shortcuts take between 20 and 25 seconds to work (ex. Ctrl+Alt+T to open a terminal, Print Screen or Alt+PrtScr to take screenshots, Super+E to open nautilus,...)
**Solution**: remove dbus-user-session package.
apt remove dbus-user-session